# How do I Navigate to a user dashboard if user form already exist and otherwise if no user profile form react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, profile

I created a user sign up and sign in form using firebase. After the user sign in, they are redirected to a profileform screen where they fill a form that is stored in Firestone, I want a situation where, if the user already filled a form he should be redirected to his dashboard else he should be redirected to profileform screen...

This is how I did it, I might be missing something
`

```
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users"));
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}`);
});
if(doc.id != null){
//navigate to dashboard 
}
else{
//navigate to profileform}
```

`

I got the profileform of a particular user, using doc.id

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure if I understand where the question is, you're saying that you did the thing you intended to do. Please consider editing with more information so that your question or where you ran into problems is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should write your code in forEach like that

```
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users"));
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}`);
if(doc.id != null){
 //navigate to dashboard 
}
else{
//navigate to profileform}
});
```

Comment: I don't understand, can you please elaborate?

Comment: dude you wrote your code out the foreach but you are using forEach item 'cause of that u should write like me check my code